# RazorViewEngine.FindPartialView useCache. What does it do?

Tags: c#, caching, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to render a partial view to string, so I can render a Razor syntax partial view into an Asp.net view. Part of the process involves getting the view engine to find the view:

```
var engine = 
    ViewEngines.Engines
        .OfType<RazorViewEngine>()
        .SingleOrDefault();
if(engine == null)throw new Exception("no razor viewengine");
//useCache is the last parameter in the invocation below
var viewResult = engine
    .FindPartialView(htmlHelper.ViewContext, viewName, false);
```

If I set the `useCache` parameter to `true` (i.e. I don't want the virtual path provider to search for it every time I ask for it), the view is no longer found. I would have expected that if it's not found via cache, we'd fall back to non-cached method.

Are my expectations wrong? Is this something to do with mixing ViewEngines?

Confusing me further, if we simply ask the `ViewEngine.Engines` collection to find the view, we're not given a `useCache` parameter:

```
var viewResult = 
    ViewEngines
         .Engines
         .FindPartialView(htmlHelper.ViewContext, viewName);
```

I think I'll go with this FTTB, but it begs the question... why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FindView` and the `FindPartialView` methods are internally called by the ASP.NET MVC framework with `useCache=true` first, then `useCache=false` if nothing is found. You could try doing the same.

> Confusing me further, if we simply ask the ViewEngine.Engines
>   collection to find the view, we're not given a useCache parameter:

That's because this method does what I explained previously.

Comment: Grand. That makes it seem more sensible. Just stumbling through the MVC code myself right now.

Comment: OK. The implementation of ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView clears things up. Thanks @Darin.

Comment: I looked at the decompiled source, but I can't seem to access the `useCache` parameter to forcefully prevent caching. How do I access the `useCache` parameter via `ViewEngines.Engines`?